# Decoding cookie value in jsp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

Hello I am encoding the cookie vlaue using javascript and then decoding it in jsp. Please find the code below -

Encoding using javascript -

```
document.cookie="email="+encodeURIComponent($scope.user.email)+";expires="+now.toGMTString()+";path=/";
```

Fetching values using request.getCookie() and then decoding in jsp -

```
email=URLDecoder.decode(cookies[3].getValue(),"UTF-8");
```

the problem here is when I am sending the same  value I am getting an error. Please find the error in the image attached. I think its decoding problem. I tried to replace `%40` with `'@'` but still the error persists. can anybody please let me know what is the issue ? The value I am sending is as below :

```
<a  ng-click='logout(<%=email%>)'></a>
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeyI1.png)

Comment: pass value as String (<a  ng-click='logout(\"<%=email%>\")'></a>)

Comment: @AravinthanK Error pops up in the console in doing so `Unexpected next character  at columns 7-7 [\] in expression [logout(\"abhi@ymail.com\")].`

Comment: try this -> <a href="logout('<%=email%>')">Link</a> ( will work)

Answer (score 0):

You must pass an email as **string**.

(i.e)

```
<a href="logout('<%=email%>')">Link</a>
```